# Описание событий

Tags: wpf, события

Где взять описание событий на RU или ENG языках ?

Яндекс по запросам , "события WPF", "описание событий WPF" ничего не дал(

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

На MSDN. Открываете класс и смотрите какие у него есть события и описания к ним.

Например: [Класс Button (System.Windows.Controls)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.button(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Посмотреть описание класса, определенных методов можно на [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library)

Также, если стоит `JetBrains Resharper` - то можно декомпилировать и посмотреть на коментарии, но на заметку - некоторые методы не имеют комментариев. Ну и со временем, понять что делает метод из стандартной библиотеки .net можно просто по названию.